# Is it allowed to minify Google +1 button and Twitter's follow button?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I recently added a +1 button and the new Twitter's follow button and I would like to minify them.. Is minifying the button's script's is allowed?

It means that i would like to minify this for twitter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                       (function(){
            var twitterWidgets = document.createElement('script');
            twitterWidgets.type = 'text/javascript';
            twitterWidgets.async = true;
            twitterWidgets.src = '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(twitterWidgets);
            })();
            </script>
```

and this for google+:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                     (function() {
                var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                })();
                </script
```

I tried to check it out in thier FAQ section, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advanced, Din.

Answer (score 1):

You can minify them if you want but minifying the dozen lines isn't going to make much of a difference. The amount of effort to minify them is probably more effort then the gain you will get.